# Select points within a given distance from a selected point

Tags: arcmap, point

What I want to do:

1. In ArcMap, let the user select a point (not a point pre-enter) and enter a range (like a Message BOX can enter range)
2. the point (pre-enter the data and XY) within range will be selected

The above is in GIS, the following is an SQL(?) problem:

3. I can get selected point's data (in a database) and make it in a table (for my Kriging)

Is there any function/tool/script in arctoolbox that can do the step 1 and 2?

@ujjwalesri
Pre-enter means I have a point.shp and in the shapefile I have enter point's xy that can display in the ArcMap.

The range that I am talking about is User can enter a range (Kilometers) and the point in the shapefile within the range will be selected (maybe use a Msgbox).

It's just like a buffer range.

Comment: What is a point pre-enter? What range are you talking about? Please clarify in simplest terms for us to be able to help you...

Comment: OK...you basically you have a point feature Shapefile and you'd like to select point features from it based upon a range. Now it's much more clear. Just another query, is the range a linear distance or could you make it interactive i.e. user draws a rectangle and selects features within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Buffer and Select Features tool](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14470) on the arcscripts web site allows the user to enter a distance value within a form, then Shift/click within the ArcMap view to select all features within the entered distance.  The tool draws a buffer graphic and selects the features within the graphic.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcMap 10 you can use the Select by Circle tool. Activate the tool from the Standard Toolbar using the drop down for Select tools. Click on the point and drag on the map. While dragging, press the R key. In the box that opens, enter the radius. All selectable features within that radius of the point you clicked will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this interactively using [Select By Location](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) under the Select menu, or automatically by using the [Select Layer by Location](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) tool under the Data Management Toolbox. Use the option **Within a distance** to enter your parameters. This is feature has been there since the very early versions of ArcMap and of course is also available in ArcPro...